# Handle various shapes of distribution in data preprocessing

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, normality-assumption, data-preprocessing, exploratory-data-analysis

Lately i have just learned about EDA, and through the `distplot` i saw that the distributions of my features and target the distributions are various. I barely observe the distribution of my data and i always think that anything skewed or not normally distributed could be fixed with simple standardization e.g applying `Standar Scaler`. The various distributions makes me question if simple standardization is enough for that case. Is applying simple standardization good enough to handle various distributions? Are distributions outside normal distributions bad input for the model?

Here is what i found from my `distplot`
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not tell us your goal, but from mentioning "features" and "target" it looks like it is regression/prediction. While it is a good idea to look at your data/learn EDA, your mindset of needing to find some standardization/normalization/transformation is misguided. There are **no normal assumption directly on the variables in regression**, any such assumptions are on error terms/residuals, so can only be judged after fitting some model. This have been said very many times on this site ... so just search the site.

Otherwise, your post is very broad, so if you want some specific advice with your data, ask a question with context.